# Can't open a new html page with JSON data after POSTING the data in flask

Tags: javascript, html, json, python-3.x, flask

I have a html file with a search bar, once a button is clicked JavaScript will get the information from that searchbar and use Flask to post it to a python function where I can then use the query from the user to search for a JSON file that has some generated html in it. After finding the JSON file I would then like to return a render_template function for another page passing that JSON data through as a variable.

My main page simplified looks like this

```html
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <input id="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
    <button onclick="load_generated_html()"><img src='img_src'></button>
{% endblock %}
```

Later in a JavaScript file I have

```js
function load_generated_html()
{
    // Get the data from the searchbar
    var searchbar = document.getElementById('searchbar')

    // Create and send a json object
    var entry = {
                    file_name: searchbar.value
                }
    send_json(entry, 'load_generated_html')
}


function send_json(data, url)
{
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/' + url,
          {
              method: 'POST',
              credentials: 'include',
              body: JSON.stringify(data),
              cache: 'no-cache',
              headers: new Headers({
                                      'content-type': 'application/json'
                                  })
          })
}
```

Then finally in a python file

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/load_generated_html', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def load_generated_html():
    file_name  = request.get_json()['file_name']
    html       = find_json(file_name)['html']

    return render_template('generated.html', name=file_name, html=html)
```

I then use {{ html }} in generated.html however even though I return render_template nothing happens. I'm still stuck on index.html. I know that the JSON data is getting passed because after some debugging I was able to find out that bit works. But for some reason Flask is not opening generated.html at all. I had a look around at some similar questions on here but none of then seem to have the answer I'm looking for. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have over-complicated a simple task. There is no need of JS.
Your HTML file should look like this:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action="{{url_for('load_generated_html')}}">
        <input name="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
        <button type="submit"><img src='img_src'></button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Your Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/load_generated_html', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def load_generated_html():
    file_name = request.form.get('searchbar')
    html = find_json(file_name)['html'] # Assuming find_json is your internal funtion

    return render_template('generated.html', name=file_name, html=html)
```

Comment: Thanks, and yeah I have a habit of over-complicating things. But this works great.